# Add data to new column based on a different table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I need to add values to a new table but I have a problem with one of the columns.  The table is named `Staff` which shows staff information and whether they are full time or part time.

The `Staff` table includes their `staff ID, First Name, Last Name, Department, Pay Grade, FullPartTime as a Bit` where 1 is full time and 0 is part time.

For the first 5 columns I'm pulling the information from a table called `Employees`, the `FullTimePartTime` column needs to come from a table called `WorkPattern`. This table has a column that shows total weekly working minutes (`WkMins`).

If the `Employee` has total work minutes of 2220, then they are full time (anything from 37 hours to 45 hours is full time) anything below is part time.

How do I insert 1 or 0 into the `FullPartTime` column in this case?

I've tried several ways but didn't keep copies of them. I tried a case but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Pleasre provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: Sounds like the full or part-time column could be computed as needed using a view or within the application itself. All the information you need to determine whether or not an employee is full time is already stored in the WorkPattern table. Any particular reason you need to duplicate that information into the Employee table? Can they adjust WkMins in any way after the week occurred?

Comment: If it were me I'd just use the existing table, this is what's been asked.

Comment: Is WkMins the total number of minutes worked per week per employee? If so, seems like the employee can be full time one week and part time the next. Whenever this SQL runs to update the full time/part time flag, do you know exactly which week should be looked at? Would it be the last one that just passed?